# Deserialize wsdl soap service (suds)

Tags: .net, python, service, wsdl, suds

The page of the service show this.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

```
svcutil.exe http://url/?wsdl
```

This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:

**C#**

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SaeServicesClient client = new SaeServicesClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

**Visual Basic**

```
Class Test
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim client As SaeServicesClient = New SaeServicesClient()
        ' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        ' Always close the client.
        client.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The response of the client.

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( SaeService ) tns="http://tempuri.org/"
Prefixes (3)
   ns0 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ImproveIT.SAE.Services"
   ns1 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"
   ns2 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
Ports (1):
   (BasicHttpBinding_ISaeServices)
      Methods (8):
         GetCliente(xs:anyType claveCliente, )
         GetPedido(xs:anyType clavePedido, )
         GetPedidos()
         GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo(xs:dateTime fechaInicial, xs:dateTime fechaFinal, )
         GetProducto(xs:anyType claveProducto, )
         GetProductos()
         GetVendedor(xs:anyType claveVendedor, )
         IsAlive()
      Types (18):
         ns0:ArrayOfPedidoDTO
         ns0:ArrayOfProductoDTO
         ns0:ClienteDTO
         ns1:Exception
         ns0:GetClienteResponse
         ns0:GetPedidoResponse
         ns0:GetPedidosResponse
         ns0:GetProductoResponse
         ns0:GetProductosResponse
         ns0:GetVendedorResponse
         ns0:PartidaDTO
         ns0:PedidoDTO
         ns0:ProductoDTO
         ns0:Response
         ns0:VendedorDTO
         ns2:char
         ns2:duration
         ns2:guid
```

**fragment of code**

```
client = suds.client.Client(url)
client.service.GetVendedor(id)
```

**xml**

```
<wsdl:definitions name="SaeService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.200:8450/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.200:8450/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.200:8450/?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ImproveIT.SAE.Services"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.200:8450/?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_IsAlive_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IsAlive"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_IsAlive_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IsAliveResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetProductos_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProductos"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetProductos_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProductosResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetProducto_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProducto"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetProducto_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProductoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetPedidos_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPedidos"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetPedidos_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPedidosResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetPedido_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPedido"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetPedido_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPedidoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetVendedor_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetVendedor"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetVendedor_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetVendedorResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetCliente_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCliente"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISaeServices_GetCliente_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetClienteResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ISaeServices">
<wsdl:operation name="IsAlive">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/IsAlive" message="tns:ISaeServices_IsAlive_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/IsAliveResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_IsAlive_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProductos">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetProductos" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetProductos_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetProductosResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetProductos_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProducto">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetProducto" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetProducto_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetProductoResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetProducto_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPedidos">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidos" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetPedidos_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidosResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetPedidos_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempoResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPedido">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedido" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetPedido_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidoResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetPedido_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVendedor">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetVendedor" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetVendedor_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetVendedorResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetVendedor_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCliente">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetCliente" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetCliente_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetClienteResponse" message="tns:ISaeServices_GetCliente_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISaeServices" type="tns:ISaeServices">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="IsAlive">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/IsAlive" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProductos">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetProductos" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProducto">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetProducto" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPedidos">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidos" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedidosCargadosEnPeriodoTiempo" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPedido">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetPedido" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVendedor">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetVendedor" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCliente">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISaeServices/GetCliente" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SaeService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ISaeServices" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ISaeServices">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.1.200:8450/Sae"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

An the error I get, with all the methods except IsAlive().

suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:claveProducto. The InnerException message was 'Element claveProducto from namespace http://tempuri.org/ cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.